# Pressing the green key in blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry

I want to know when the user presses the green button in the device to initiate a phonecall from the app directly. What event is fired when the green key is pressed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to be something similar to this.

Override keyDown:

```
public boolean keyDown(int keycode, int time)
{
   if (keycode == Keypad.SEND)
  {
    //handle your event
    return true;
  }
  return super.keyDown(keycode, time);
}
```

Comment: if (keycode == 1114112) {
    //handle my work
}
cause 1114112 represents the green key

Comment: Guys, you've messed up keys and keycodes! It should be `if (Keypad.key(keycode) == Keypad.SEND) { //handle your event
 .. }`. Don't hardcode 1114112 ("magic number" anti-pattern), there is no guarantee that in other/future OS the value is still the same.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement KeyListener

```
import net.rim.device.api.system.KeyListener;
```

override the function

```
public boolean keyDown(int keycode, int time)
```

and inside it catch the event of pressing buttons.

How do you check which button was pressed?

```
if (Keypad.KEY_SEND == Keypad.key(keycode)) {//your code}
```

find the API DOC here : http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Keypad.html